# List domains that contain a string

Tags: ontology, jena

first off all I´m new to Jena. I´ve created an ontology and i´ve 4 classes, procedure, buyer, supplier and Zip Code.And i´ve the following properties:

1. Procedure hasBuyer Buyers
2. Procedure hasSupplier Supplier
3. Supplier hasZipCode Zip Code
4. Buyer hasZipCode Zip Code

What i want to know it´s the best approach in Jena to return all domains that contain a string "3333".

For example:

- Procedure 1 have buyer 1 with zip code 333, supplier 1 with zip code 333 and supplier2 with zip code 334.
- Procedure 2 have buyer 2 with zip code 331, supplier 2 with zip code 334 and supplier2 with zip code 335.
- Procedure 3 have buyer 3 with zip code 333, supplier 1 with zip code 333 and supplier3 with zip code 335.

The results must be:

- Procedures - Procedure1 and Procedure3
- Buyer - Buyer1 and Buyer 3
- Supplier - supplier1

NG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't use "supplier 2 with zip code 334", and then "supplier 2 with zip code 335", because it's the same individual, and you'll see "supplier 2 with zip code 334 and zip code 334" in application both times.

There is some variants of realisation.

With plain Jena API:

```
Model model; // your model
Resource supplierClass = model.getResource(YOUR_NS + "Supplier");
Resource buyerClass = model.getResource(YOUR_NS + "Buyer");
Resource procClass = model.getResource(YOUR_NS + "Procedure");
Property zipCodeProp = model.getProperty(YOUR_NS + "zipCode");
Property hasBuyerProp = model.getProperty(YOUR_NS + "hasBuyer");
Property hasSupplierProp = model.getProperty(YOUR_NS + "hasSupplier");
StmtIterator iter = 
        model.listStatements(new SimpleSelector(null, zipCodeProp, "333"));
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Resource subject = iter.next().getSubject();
    if (!subject.hasProperty(RDF.type))
        continue;
    Resource subjectClass = subject.getPropertyResourceValue(RDF.type);
    SimpleSelector sel;
    if (subjectClass.equals(supplierClass))
        sel = new SimpleSelector(null, hasSupplierProp, subject);
    else if (subjectClass.equals(buyerClass))
        sel = new SimpleSelector(null, hasBuyerProp, subject);
    else
        continue;
    StmtIterator innerIter = model.listStatements(sel);
    while (innerIter.hasNext()) {
        Resource proc = innerIter.next().getSubject();
        if (!proc.hasProperty(RDF.type) || 
                !proc.getPropertyResourceValue(RDF.type).equals(procClass))
            continue;
        // now you can retrieve linked entities from this procedure
    }
}
```

And SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX yourns: <YOUR_NS>
SELECT DISTINCT ?proc
{
    ?proc a yourns:Procedure;
          yourns:hasBuyer ?buyer;
          yourns:hasSupplier ?supplier.
    ?supplier zipCode ?supplierZip.
    ?buyer zipCode ?buyerZip.
    FILTER (?supplierZip = '333' || ?buyerZip = '333')
}
```

with further use of ARQ:

```
Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
while (results.hasNext()) {
    QuerySolution qs = results.next();
Resource proc = qs.getResource("proc");
    // now again you can retrieve linked entities
}
```

Comment: Hi Lev, Thanks for your reply. This week i can´t try your solution. Next week i will. NG PS: I forgot to change suplier number ;)